# Transform a string to a hash

Tags: perl

Is there any way/lib to transform a string to a hash ?
I have such string

```
{"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"}
```

and I would like to access the different values like if it was a hash

Thank you

Comment: You can use `eval`, but it's not recommended. Where has this string come from?

Comment: From db, it's legacy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using eval():

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = qw( {"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"} );
print "String: $string\n";

my $hash = eval($string);
print "Hash: ", Dumper($hash), "\n";
```

**Output**

```
String: {"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"}
Hash: $VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar',
          'hello' => [
                       'world',
                       'perl'
                     ]
        };
```

Using reval() and [Safe](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html) if you are at all concerned about the input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Safe;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = qw( {"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"} );
print "String: $string\n";

my $compartment = new Safe;
my $hash = $compartment->reval($string);
print $@ ? "reval error: $@" : ("Hash: ", Dumper($hash)), "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string with Perl data structure to a string with JSON data structure by substitute `=>` with `:` and decode it with JSON package.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON qw(decode_json); # use JSON::XS for more performance

my $string = '{"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"}';
$string =~ s/"=>/":/g;
print Dumper(decode_json($string));
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => [
                       'world',
                       'perl'
                     ],
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

Comment: Doesn't work for this: `$string = '{123=>"my number"}'` and also not for `$string = '{"=>hello"=>"world"}'`. Your solution might be ok, but it should be mentioned that it requires that you to know what input might come. Now and in the future.

Comment: @KjetilS You are right. We know nothing about the producer of the string. You can harden this solution by extend the regex. Or you can enable the producer to serialize real Json or to produce a serialized Perl data structure.

Comment: @Theo: *"You are right. We know nothing about the producer of the string"* Quite. So your answer cannot stand.

Comment: @Borodin: I disagree. It needs tuning by the requestor to fit its specific requirements. And in production environment it is always better than eval. You never know which evil strings are in the database. decode only fails. eval has the potential to kill your system.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind me plugging one of my own modules: [`Config::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Perl) uses [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) to parse strings like that, with no need for [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; # Debug
use Config::Perl;

my $str = q( {"hello"=>["world","perl"],"foo"=>"bar"} );

my $data = Config::Perl->new->parse_or_die(\$str)->{_}[0];

print Dumper($data); # Debug
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => [
                       'world',
                       'perl'
                     ],
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```

(The above code assumes that you've only got a single hash ref in your data, if you've got variations, you'll have to look at the whole data structure returned by `parse_or_die`.)

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with PPI until your answer.